# Adding dyndns hostname to /etc/hosts with Alias

Tags: macos, hosts, hosts-file

I configued my router to work with dyndns. Instead of using the dyndns hostname created by dyndns.org, I want to define my own host name, that in tern, refers to that dyndns hostname.

For example, lets say my dyndns hostname is fanix.dyndns.org, when I ping that address, it resolves to my ADSL router IP address, which is correct.

On my mac, I wish to use a shorter name, for instance, xNas, so that when I issue command "ping xNas", it uses the etc/hosts file and pings the dyndns hostname. But this isn;'t working. I added the following in /private/etc/hosts

```
fanix.dyndns.org xNas
```

When I ping xNas, it returns

```
ping: cannot resolve xnas: Unknown host
```

How do I get this to work?

**NOTE: I do not have a static IP address, I have ADSL, so my IP address changes.**

Comment: It's possible to do what you're asking, but by using a dns server, not with the hosts file alone. At least as far as I know. It would be a lot easier to use an alias or export if you were only using it in terminal. Otherwise, you need a dns server. I do this exact thing with DyDNS, but I use an externally hosted DNS server for the forwarding to the DyDNS name (which then forwards to the dynamic IP).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with Search Domains, sort of.

If you go to your TCP/IP settings and add `dyndns.org` as a search domain then whenever you ping

```
ping fanix
```

It will first try to resolve fanix in your local domain - perhaps `fanix.local` and if it doesn't get a hit, it will then look for `fanix.dyndns.org`.

This is one extra character than you were after, but saves the need for a DNS server.